# Couchdb unable to connect to Peer in Podman

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, podman

The Couchdb container is unable to connect with the peer container internally through podman, despite using the same environment exports for docker as well. In the case of docker, the internal connection between couchdb and peer is occurring.

The image used for couchdb is localhost/hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:latest

These are exports used for the environment of the peer

```
      -e FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info \
      -e ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info \
      -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=nodeaMSP \
      -e CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.nodea \
      -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.nodea:7051 \
      -e CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 \
      -e CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.nodea:7052 \
      -e CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052 \
      -e CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.nodea:7051 \
      -e CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.nodea:7051 \
      -e CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB \
      -e CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb7:5984 \
      -e CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=admin \
      -e CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=admin \
      -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true \
      -e CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.crt \
      -e CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/server.key \
      -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls/ca.crt \
      -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp \
      -e CORE_PEER_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/podman/podman.sock \
```

What can be done to enable the connection between the peer container and couchdb container?